How to Calculate Integrated Autocorrelation Time (IAT) for Multiple MCMC Chains?
I am running multiple Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) chains in parallel, and I want to compute the integrated autocorrelation time (IAT) for the overall sample. While I understand how to compute the IAT for a single chain based on the autocorrelation function $ \rho(t) $, I’m unsure how to handle multiple chains .
Here are some specific points I’m unclear about:

Should I calculate the autocorrelation function $\rho(t)$ for each chain separately and then average the IATs across chains?
What would be the recommended approach if the chains have not reached the same stationary distribution (e.g., if the R-hat statistic is far from 1)?

Any references or example implementations (in Python or R) would also be helpful!
